Help on a maths Olympiad question - Expected Values
I recently encountered an unfamiliar stats/probability olympiad question that I had no idea how to start. I tried simpler cases with 2 people, but it didn't seem to help.

100 people stand in a circle all facing inwards. Each person raises either their left hand, right hand or both sideways. If two adjacent people have their hands extended towards each other, they hold hands.Find the expected value for the number of pairs of hands held in total.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[1] What are the probabilities of the various actions ? [2] Can you edit in whatever efforts you have made, and where you are stuck ?

Welcome to MSE! Keep in mind, it's always good around here to show any attempts you've already had, and where specifically you got stuck (as @true blue anil said). Have fun! :]

Clarification request: the way that I interpret the problem, the three events of right hand only, left hand only, or both hands each have a probability of $~(1/3).~$  Is my interpretation of the problem correct?

That was the question on the paper and I assume the probabilities for each option are equal, hence each having the probability of 1/3 :)

$400/9.$
Consider the edge $e=(i,i+1)$ (Convention $X_{101}=X_1$) Denote $X_i=-1$ if $i$ uses left arm only, $X_i=1$ if $i$ uses right arm only and $X_i=0$ if $i$ uses both arms. One assumes $\Pr(X_i=\pm 1)=\Pr(X_i=0)=1/3$, that all $X_i$ are independent and that $i+1$ is at the right of $i.$ An array analysing the 9 cases shows that the edge $e$ is closed in 4 cases, that is the probability that $e$ is closed is 4/9. The results between all the edges are not independent, nevertheless expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of expectations. Computation of the variance would be another story.
